# reload contents of a page using ajax without refresh

Tags: jquery, ajax

i want to reload the contents of a page using ajax without actually refreshing the page. so using ajax, ALL of contents of the page changes without actually reloading the page. How can I do that?

I can't use a div because I want to replace the whole page (and thus want to be w3c html validating compliant).

how can I do this using jquery and ajax?

Comment: What is your goal?  Why do you want to use Ajax instead of reloading the page?

Comment: trying to do a login form. so people login and the whole page refreshes and recognizes them as a logged in member.

Comment: If you want to refresh the whole page then why not just reload without ajax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AJAX came about for scenarios where updating an entire page wasn't resource effective (i.e. when only part of the page is going to be updated after a request). For your example, a page refresh sounds ideal - since all content is going to be changed anyway.

AJAX isn't the best answer in every situation, but if you are adamant to solving your problem with AJAX...

Using jQuery:

```
$.post('/login', {login: 'username', password: 'password'}, function(response) { $('body').html(response); }, 'text');
```

Note, this only updates the body - so the response shouldn't include `html`, `head`, `body`, etc.

A better solution would be to assign sections to parts of your page, addressable by AJAX updates. Your AJAX responders could then return an associative array containing the ID of these sections as the keys, and their contents as the values. A simple loop could then update any (or all) parts of the page with little modification to the snippet I provided above.